# Selecting the last item of a chained class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to target the last items of a chained class. By this, I mean each item may have an `entry` class, and if two leading items have the same 'entry' class, then it becomes chained.

How may I do this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6vsR/1/)

```
<ul class="date">
    <li class="entry"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="entry"></li>
    <li class="entry"></li>
    <li class="entry"></li> /* target this item */
    <li></li>
    <li class="entry"></li>
    <li class="entry"></li> /* target this item */
    <li></li>
</ul>


/* targets all chained classes */
.entry + .entry { }

/* targets first of a chained class */
:not(.entry) + .entry { }
```

Comment: Will there always be `<li></li>` after the ones you want to target?

Comment: Note that `:not(.entry) + .entry { }` does not necessarily target the "first of a chained class", as it would also target a "lone entry" of that class (non-chained) that was _not the first child_ of the group.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, what you need is to use `.entry:last-of-type { }`

**EDIT**

I'm sorry I forgot to mention that this will only work if all elements containing this class are of the same type (e.g. all of them are divs).

If this is a problem for you, you could easily solve this problem with jQuery, like this:

```
var entries = $(".entry"); //here we have an array with all elements that have the class entry
var wantedEntry = entries[entries.length - 1]; //last element of the array;
```

I'm not sure there is a plain solution using pure CSS only, so I hope this helps.

**EDIT 2**

I'm sorry for being so slow, but now that I really get your point, I don't think there is a pure CSS way to achieve what you want. Again, I know of some possible solutions via jQuery coding, but as I don't know if jQuery is an option, I won't bother you with that.

Comment: That won't select the first one he has marked with `target this item`.

Comment: Oh darn that's right, I'll edit my answer again then, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

I would think your best bet would be to break these list items up into separate lists.

```
<ul class="date">
    <li class="entry"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="entry"></li>
  <li class="entry"></li>
  <li class="entry"></li> /* target this item */
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="entry"></li>
  <li class="entry"></li> /* target this item */
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.entry:last-child{
  background: red;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/pamivosa/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Haven't been able to figure a way to do it through CSS yet, but accomplished what I wanted using jQuery.

```
$('.date li').each(function() {

    var self = $(this);
    if(self.hasClass('entry') && self.next().hasClass('entry'))
        self.addClass('rightborder').next().addClass('leftborder');

});

.rightborder {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.leftborder {           
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6vsR/25/)